# why this Singleton in c++11 does't work well?

Tags: c++, c++11, singleton

```
#include <memory>
#include <mutex>

template<typename T>
class Singleton
{
    public:
    Singleton() = default;
    ~Singleton() = default;
    //forbid copy and asign
    Singleton(const Singleton &) = delete;
    Singleton&operator=(const Singleton&) = delete;

    //make singleton instance by args
    template <typename...Args>
    static void makeInstance(Args&&...args)
    {
        std::call_once(flag, make_shared_instance<T>, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

    //get instance
    static std::shared_ptr<T> Instance()
    {
        if (!instance)
        {
            throw std::exception("instance not make!");
        }

        return instance;
    }

private:
    template <typename...Args>
    static void make_shared_instance(Args&&...args)
    {
        instance = std::make_shared<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

    static std::once_flag flag;
    static std::shared_ptr<T> instance;
};

int main()
{
    Singleton<double>::makeInstance(10);   // OK
    Singleton<int>::makeInstance();        // compilation error
}
```

When I use it like this with parameters

```
Singleton<double>::makeInstance(10);
```

it works well but without parameters

```
Singleton<int>::makeInstance();
```

it doesn't work. Why is this?

Comment: What's the point of using shared ownership of a singleton? It lives until the shutdown of your program.

Comment: Just a warning: Be careful with template based singletons especially when working with libraries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an error in your `makeInstance` function; you're specializing `make_shared_instance` with the wrong template parameter. The correct code is

```
std::call_once(flag, make_shared_instance<Args...>, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
//                                       ^^^^^^^^
```

Your code with `Singleton<double>::makeInstance(10);` works because the argument of type `int` is convertible to `double`. But when you call it as `Singleton<int>::makeInstance();`, `make_shared_instance<int>` expects an argument and you haven't provided any.

---

Also, [`std::exception`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception/exception) doesn't have a constructor that takes a string literal argument. You're probably using VC++, which has a non-standard constructor that allows your code to compile. You should probably throw [`std::runtime_error`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/runtime_error) instead.

Comment: yes , you are right , it is ok now , thanks for your help